# Am i mutating state? If so what solutions are available?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, state, react-state-management

I have a simple component, which builds a list of reports from an array of objects, i'm trying to add filter and sort functionality (which does work - to a degree), The sort functionality works, but i fear i'm mutating state despite trying to copy the original state into a new array.

My filter works for the firs time, but then it will not filter other results because state has been mutated, or because i cannot filter through the initial state? This has had me confused for hours now, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks very much

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        reports: props.data
    };
    this.handleSortBy = this.handleSortBy.bind(this);
    this.handleFilterType = this.handleFilterType.bind(this);
}

handleSortBy(event) {
    const copy = [...this.state.reports];
    if (event.target.value === 'A-Z') {
        return this.setState({
            reports: copy.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
        });
    }
    if (event.target.value === 'Z-A') {
        this.setState({
            reports: copy
                .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
                .reverse()
        });
    }
}

handleFilterType(event) {
    this.setState({
        reports: this.state.reports.filter(item => {
            return item.type === event.target.value;
        })
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to do it depending on your use-case is to replace `this.state.reports` with `this.props.data` in your two update functions. (Although, if you do it this way, you couldn't apply sort and filter at the same time)

But I agree with ModestLeech that it's better to store the filter in state instead.  To do that, change your filter code to something like:

```
handleFilterType(event) {
    this.setState({
        filter: event.target.value;
        })
    });
}
```

And in your render method, assuming you're using a map, you can change the map to `this.state.reports.filter(item => (this.state.filter===undefined || item.type===this.state.filter)).map(...)`.

**EDIT:**

There are two types of mutation you need to worry about with React.

One is not mutating your props (i.e. mutating state that your component doesn't control).  Since Javascript passes in arrays and objects by reference, if you were to `sort` on `this.props.data` it would actually modify the array that exists in your component's parent (or grandparent, or wherever it's defined).  The good news is that your original code avoided that already - possibly accidentally.  `handleSortBy` made a copy of the array before mutating it, and `handleFilterType` uses `Array.prototype.filter`, which creates a new array.

The second mutation you have to worry about is changing local state without using `setState`.  Calling `this.state.reports.sort(...)` in `render` will change local state, but React won't know and won't re-render. This isn't a problem, since you're sorting right before you need it, but directly mutating state is dangerous because it could lead to bugs where you as the developer think something should or should not change under certain conditions but the reality is different.

Your original problem with `filter` had nothing to do with accidental mutation.  The issue was that by calling `this.setState` the first time with a filter, you overwrote `this.state.reports` and had no way to get it back.  It also had the problem that if `this.props.data` ever changes in the parent, the new reports would never appear in this component since you only read the props when the component is first created.

The recommended React way of doing this is not to store something in state that comes from a prop unless you are just using the prop to set some initial state and all future updates will come from inside the component.  But assuming this component does not ultimately own the list of reports, it would be simpler in the long run to make a copy of `this.props.data` in `render` and apply your sort and filter to it.  Then, if anything is added or removed higher in the component tree, you won't have to write any special logic to update the local state of this component.

Comment: Hi @aelfric5578, thanks for your answer, this kind of works, but when the component loads my list is empty, it doesnt populate until one of the filters have been applied?

Comment: Also, am i mutating state with my sort method, even though im copying the state and filtering with that?

Comment: Yes, you are.  `this.setState` always mutates state.  Basically, what you are doing is permanently changing the list each time.  By copying the list, you are not modifying the inputs to the component (i.e. `this.props.data`) but you are changing the local state of the component.

To your other question, that can be fixed by changing the filter function `.filter(item => (this.state.filter === undefined || item.type===this.state.filter))`

Comment: Thanks very much, i will mark your answer as correct, Is this bad that i am mutating state this way? I need to re arrange the order of my reports, and filter them etc.

Comment: It's not bad per se, but it's a bit dangerous.  If `this.props.data` changes, `this.state.reports` will never get the updates.  You can avoid mutating on sorting by storing a flag in state instead.  Something like (untested) `.sort((a, b) => this.state.sortASC ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name)) : b.name.localeCompare(a.name))`  (you would also then call this in render instead of the callback.

Comment: .sort((a, b) => {
       if (this.state.sort !== undefined) {
        return this.state.sort === 'A-Z'
         ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
         : b.name.localeCompare(a.name);
       }
      })

This worked! brilliant, thanks again!

Comment: just a thought >>>> {reports
      .sort((a, b) => {
       if (sort !== undefined) {
        return sort === 'A-Z'
         ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
         : b.name.localeCompare(a.name);
       }
       return reports;
      })
      .filter(
       item => filter === undefined || item.type === filter
      )
      .map(report => (...) 

doesn't that still mutate this.state.reports?

Comment: Yes.  `sort` still modifies the array, so you'd have to copy it before sorting.

Comment: Im a little confused now, as thats what im doing in my original question, I copied this.state.reports into const copy =[], then sorted with that, if that mutated the array still then i seem to be going round in a circle?

Comment: I added some more context to my answer.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is each time you filter, you are removing items from `state.reports`, and are never getting them back from `props.data`.

Instead you should reconstruct `state.reports` from `props.data` each time you filter/sort.

Or a better way, IMO, would be to store the filtering/sorting settings in `state`, and do the filtering/sorting of `props.data` in `render` based on the current settings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, would it be possible to get some examples please?